# Postgresql character type for Russian UTF-8 DB creation?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

There are following choices of character type in window "Create Database": `en_US.UTF8`, `C`, `POSIX`. But database will be with data in Russian language. How to choose `ru_RU.UTF8`?

If it's not needed, what of the above should I choose? DB encoding is UTF8.

EDIT:
PostgreSQL version: 8.4
OS: CentOS 6 in VirtualBox
Locale: I don't know, I use both languages
Yes, I use pgAdmin3
"If you select template0 as the template database do the offered options change?" - No

Comment: PostgreSQL version? Platform/operating system? What's the OS's locale? Does the OS have a ru_RU.UTF-8 locale supported and generated? Are you using PgAdmin-III or some other program? (I guessed pgadmin3 and tagged based on that). If you select template0 as the template database do the offered options change?

Answer (score 10):

For a Russian `UTF-8` database you indeed want `ru_RU.UTF-8` as your `LC_CTYPE` and `LC_COLLATE`. To create the database with SQL you would write:

```
CREATE DATABASE my_database_name 
ENCODING 'UTF-8' 
LC_COLLATE 'ru_RU.UTF-8'
LC_CTYPE 'ru_RU.UTF-8'
TEMPLATE template0;
```

Your admin tool should permit you to select these options. It's hard to say more without knowing your Pg version, which admin tool you're using, your OS/version, etc.

Comment: In addition, if you need to set the locale in Windows, use more verbose locale names, such as `German_Germany` or `Swedish_Sweden.1252`. Source: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/locale.html